# Click event on array with multiple elements but individually

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to cycle through an array with a `for...of` loop but need each element in the array to be a separate click event (not grabbing all of them) - without using jQuery.

Here's what I have so far ...

```
const dataScrollTo = document.querySelectorAll('[data-scroll-to]');
let ss = 1000;
let o = 0;

const scrollMe = function scrollMe() {
    for (const el of dataScrollTo) {
        const trigger = el.getAttribute('data-scroll-to');
        const target = document.getElementById(trigger);
        const dsoGet = el.getAttribute('data-scroll-offset');
        const dssGet = el.getAttribute('data-scroll-speed');

        target.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth'
        });

        if (dsoGet) {
            o = dsoGet;
        }
        if (dssGet) {
            ss = dssGet;
        }
    }
};
document.addEventListener('click', scrollMe);
```

And the HTML (there are a few navigation divs similar to this one).

```
<div>
  <a class="icon-link" data-scroll-to="research" data-scroll-offset="60">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the event listener to each element, not `document`. The listener can use `this` to tell which element was clicked on.

```
function scrollMe() {
    const el = this;
    const trigger = el.getAttribute('data-scroll-to');
    const target = document.getElementById(trigger);
    const dsoGet = el.getAttribute('data-scroll-offset');
    const dssGet = el.getAttribute('data-scroll-speed');

    target.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth'
    });

    if (dsoGet) {
        o = dsoGet;
    }
    if (dssGet) {
        ss = dssGet;
    }
}

dataScrollTo.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", scrollMe));
```

Comment: (Line 2 has a typo. I'd edit but Stack Overflow doesn't let you just add 1 character.)

Comment: Thanks. When you get enough rep you'll be able to make edits like that.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Mucho appreciation!